# jsoup basic scraping technique

Tags: android, xml, jsoup

I have checked through all forum but i dont understand where i am wrong. basically i try to scrape the word "Sun, 04 Feb 2018" out. anyhelp will be appreciated on what concept i got wrong in this case but i keep getting no null return.

**aspx. code**

```
<div class="divLatestDraws slider" data-min-width="282">
    <div class="slide-wrapper four-d">
        <ul class="slide-container ulDraws" style="width: 1808px; margin-left: 0px;">
            <li style="width: 301.33px;"><div class="tables-wrap">
        <table class="table table-striped orange-header">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="drawDate">Sun, 04 Feb 2018</th>
```

**my jsoup code**

```
            // Connect to the web site
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            // Using Elements to get the Meta data
            Elements xxx = document.select("div[class=divLatestDraws slider]");
            Elements zzz = xxx.select("th[class=drawDate]");
            desc=zzz.body().text();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
```

Comment: `Elements` has no `body()` method. It looks to me like `zzz.first().text()` will return "Sun, 04 Feb 2018".

Comment: If the date is created dynamically by some JavaScript on the site that manipulates the DOM, then JSoup can't read it. JSoup does not run JavaScript!

Comment: ok... do you mean that the code is inside script that why i can't use text() to get the text i want? 
Cause i realize that the html portion is inside <script> 

Anyway i can resolve this, i check around how to pull the text for JSOUP within a <script> not so successful for this beginner haiz

The website is actually: http://www.singaporepools.com.sg/en/product/Pages/4d_results.aspx